# WordPress WP Ecommerce User Registration

Tags: wordpress

I’m interesting if there is a way to add registration directly to my registration page and not with checkout.

For example I don’t want to have Username at all and instead I want to use email address as one. Whereas in usual WP registration page I need to fill Username and Email and password will be emailed to me, I want to have just a page where I fill nor full blank with email and wp e-commerce details or just email -> then comes my password and I go to page where I fill the rest of the details.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, like hardcoding form for yourself with right inputs and plugins with many custom forms.

In my case in the end I used plugin as I have Multisite

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s8-custom-login-and-registration/ S8

Which works perfect for WordPress 3.5